# How do I get the current working directory in IronRuby?

Tags: ironruby

I'm wondering how I can read the current working directory of a file being "parsed" by IronRuby. It appears the "execution directory" is the same as the ir.exe file.

I need this to create a relative path to content in a XNA solution without hardcoding the path.

Answer (score 4):

From [Class:Dir](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html):

```
Dir.getwd => string
Dir.pwd => string

Returns the path to the current working directory of this process as a string.

Dir.chdir("/tmp")   #=> 0
Dir.getwd           #=> "/tmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution in Dir.pwd

Silly me forgot that pwd is not an acronym for password but for print working directory...

Embarassing :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the CLR way of doing things if you feel like it:

```
include System
Environment.current_directory => clr_string
```